# Multiple String Values in one SSRS expression

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-expression

I am having an challenge with this SSRS expression. I need add **REPORT_NAME "AIA1610U"** in the expression to narrow my results down in the report.

Not Sure what I am doing wrong here. How would I go about doing that? Any Assistance would be great.

```
=SUM(IIf(Fields!NAME.Value = "TOTAL OUTSTANDING APPLICATIONS" ,Fields!DAYS_AGO.Value ,0),"rsOutstandingApplications")- SUM(IIf(Fields!NAME.Value = "ELECTION FORM RECEIVED" ,Fields!DAYS_AGO.Value ,0), "rsOutstandingApplications" )
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The Y expression for the chart ‘Chart1’ contains an error: [BC30108] 'Field' is a type and cannot be used as an expression.

Comment: Try changing "Field!REPORT_NAME.Value" to "Fields!REPORT_NAME.Value"

Comment: it runs with no results. Is there another way to write the expression?

Comment: Well you could set the dataset of the container to be "rsOutstandingApplications", and remove that from the expression.   I'm not sure it's being implemented correctly as you have posted.

Comment: I restated my initial question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: OK, I figured my issue out. Here are the results of the correct answer.   `=SUM(IIf(Fields!NAME.Value = "TOTAL OUTSTANDING APPLICATIONS" AND Fields!REPORT_NAME.Value = "AIA1610U", Fields!DAYS_AGO.Value ,0),"rsOutstandingApplications")  - 
SUM(IIf(Fields!NAME.Value = "ELECTION FORM RECEIVED"
,Fields!DAYS_AGO.Value ,0), "rsOutstandingApplications" )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured my issue out. Here are the results of the correct answer.

```
= SUM(IIf(Fields!NAME.Value = "TOTAL OUTSTANDING APPLICATIONS" AND Fields!REPORT_NAME.Value = "AIA1610U", Fields!DAYS_AGO.Value ,0),"rsOutstandingApplications")  - 
  SUM(IIf(Fields!NAME.Value = "ELECTION FORM RECEIVED", Fields!DAYS_AGO.Value ,0), "rsOutstandingApplications" )
```